# WinUI 3 keyboard layout for input from SwapChainPanel

Tags: windows, locale, keyboard-events, winui-3, c++-winrt

I'm working on a WinUI 3 - C++/winRT - desktop application.

The application displays and updates in a window-sized XAML SwapChainPanel through Direct2D and needs to receive keyboard input from the user.  With KeyDown and KeyUp on the SwapChainPanel, I can get raw keyboard input.  However, this provides only VirtualKeys, ScanCodes, RepeatCount, etc. through the accompanying KeyRoutedEventArgs.

I can find no way to tell WinUI 3 which keyboard layout to use, nor any sort of keyboard management for such things as shift keys, etc (VirtualKeys are only capital ASCII letters).

What I've managed to do is build window messages from the KeyDowns and KeyUps and send them to TranslateMessage then DispatchMessage so they end up as WM_CHARs in the window's message loop.
This takes care of quite a bit of the shift, caps lock, etc. logic and produces Unicode.  However, it doesn't take into account the keyboard layout which, in my case, is Canadian Multilingual with four layers of characters on most keys.  I can receive some non-ASCII characters (Latin 1) but they aren't the right ones.

This must be a common situation with all the different languages in the world, but I haven't found anything in the way of a keyboard processing function that would receive raw information from the keyboard, process the control keys and output Unicode.

If the window's message pump is the only way to go (for now ?), how to get TranslateMessage to take into account the keyboard layout ?

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Are you looking for `UIElement.CharacterReceived` event? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.characterreceived

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I needed and I wonder why I didn't come across it in all my research into keyboard input.  I attached it directly to the SwapChainPanel.  Works perfectly.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it is not as simple as attaching CharacterReceived to the SwapChainPanel since the latter cannot receive focus.  I put a StackPanel with a zero-sized ContentControl on the SwapChainPanel for the sole purpose of managing focus.  The ContentControl is necessary for Focus() on the StackPanel to succeed.  There are different situations when focus is lost and it must be brought back after such occurences with stackpanel().Focus( ...::Keyboard ).  Also, control characters like cursor arrow keys must still be handled with KeyDown's and KeyUp's.